# Can Android's inbluit feature Google speech to text used by Ionic framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-speech-api

I'm trying to build an app using Ionic framework, and need to provide a speech to text feature in it.
Is it possible to configure Ionic or Cordova plugins to use Android-Google's built-in speech-to-text feature? If yes then how?